# Understanding nested SQL statement

Tags: sql, select, nested

Is there an easy way to recreate this statement? Or a way I can look it up for an example in my database? Because at the moment I don't understand what it exactly does. I think I understand the first `in` but I don't know why there are for PROJECTS two `in` clauses why the second example is not the same as the first. Thanks in advance.

```
select usernumber as usrnr from DOCUMENTS
where CompanyIndex in (
    select CompanyIndex 
    from DOCUMENTS 
    where DocumentType='3' 
      and ProjectsIndex in (select Index 
                            from PROJECTS where 
                            Projectnumber = 209806)
)
and ProjectsIndex in (
    select Index 
    from PROJECTS 
    where Projectnumber = 209806  
)
and DocumentType = '2'
```

And I don't understand why it is not the same as this

```
select ad1 as AD1Nr from DOCUMENTS
where CompanyIndex in
(
    select CompanyIndex 
    from DOCUMENTS 
    where DocumentType='3' 
      and ProjectsIndex in (select Index 
                           from PROJECTS 
                           where Projectnumber = 209806)
       and DocumentType = '2')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reformatted the code to show the structure.

The difference is now obvious: condition `DocumentType = '2'` is inside the inner select in the second sample but outside in the first.

(This is why being somewhat obsessive compulsive about formatting isn't a negative trait.)